# Is it improper form to use a 404 as a basis for a php website?

Tags: php, http-status-code-404

*(Sorry if this is a repeat question, I had a hard time thinking of how to search for it, and just came up with thousands of results about how to make 404s work.)*

I'm trying to build a PHP website that would roughly follow the form: `http://www.example.com/user/MrPoopPants`

And I was wondering the best solution for that. In also trying to figure out how URL shorteners redirect, one website suggested sending every request through a 404, and have the 404 error page assess the data with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

With that, you could just `preg_split`, and ask a database if there is a user named MrPoopPants, then just build your site with PHP based on includes and he database.

The two problems I don't like with this are: I am using a 404 for every page in the website, that seems like a really bad thing; I am also relying on a single php file for the entire website, which seems like bad form.

What would the best way to go about this be? EDIT: That is, I realize this is a bad practice, what is the solution? How do I detect the URL information without having it redirected to a 404? How do I set up a page so that when you do `/user/manboy` it knows to let `/user/user.php` read the URL and build the page?

Comment: Searching for front controllers and .htaccess URL rewriting should give you a place to start (sorry I can't provide more details; it's been a while since I've worked with this as well).

Comment: Making a site with 404s is not a good idea, mostly because that HTTP Status Code is reserved for 'NOT FOUND', which isn't really the case. You want to be sending the proper HTTP codes all the time: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are essentially asking about URL rewriting. An excellent tutorial for beginners explaining all the important bits and bytes of `mod_rewrite` can be found **[here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache/)**.

The PHP part of handling rewritten requests is I am afraid PHP 101 which no one can simply "explain" to you. You need to have a specific question about a very specific problem in order for people to be able to actually help you.

Comment: You're correct in saying I'm a beginner. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do can be accomplished with URL rewrites. Although you should really look into a PHP framework, you can do rewrites yourself.

It lets you create URLs like `http://mydomain.com/user/1` which you can handle on the server with by rewriting it to: `http://mydomain.com?q=user/1`.

You can then access the URL in code using:
`$url = $_GET['q'];`

http://www.addedbytes.com/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely look into this!

Answer (score 0):

A 404 error isn't really a tool that you use to make your website work. Instead, think of it only as the response you send to the client when what the client asked for cannot be found.

A better way of handling this is to set up your web framework so that you have a single script that responds to any URL of the form `http://www.example.com/user/_____` where anything follows the final `/`. Then you can write code to look up the user name in a database or whatever, and generate the desired result page.

Comment: I appreciate the response, but you have merely restated my concerns expressed in the question. How do I make a page that responds to a URL without apache sending the 404? If I do use '/user/manboy' how will it know to redirect to '/user/user.php'?

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here regarding rewrite rules are absolutely correct. However, I have had one situation in the past with a server hosting a ton of varied applications under one hostname where I had to do exactly what you are proposing.

Basically, due to a locked down rewrite config on a shared IIS server, I set the 404 page to a PHP script. This script would look up the attempted URL in a database to see if it was set to be redirected elsewhere.

Now the key here was that a 404 was never sent to the client. The client got a 301 or 302 with a `Location` header. The client never knew it had hit a 404 page, because it was not returned as one. (Of course, if the script couldn't find the redirect entry in the database, it would return a proper 404 page and status code.)

In short, while unconventional, there is nothing wrong with this approach if you have exhasted normal options, and are careful about how you respond to the clients.